# ¿Cómo crear un vector para un objeto Candidato.java?

Tags: java, poo

Tengo el código de un laboratorio:
public class Candidato{

```
private String nombre;
private String cedula;
private String edad;


public Candidato (String nombre, String cedula, String edad){
    setNombre (nombre);
    setCedula (cedula);
    setEdad (edad);     
}
```

}

Pero según las indicaciones, debe ir contenido en un arreglo vectot;
Indicaciones:

El Gobierno de Costa Rica está realizando las elecciones para el representante del país en la
embajada de Honduras, dicha elección se hará unicamente con votantes de cuatro
provincias: Puntarenas, Alajuela, Cartago y Guanacaste. Para dicho fin se debe crear un
vector que almacene la información de los candidatos (nombre, cedula y edad), luego una
matriz donde se almacenen los votos que ha tenido cada candidato en las 4 provincias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Soy nuevo en este sitio. Mi problema realmente es que no he logrado el aprendizaje adecuado porque mi profesor de programación no es necesariamente un gran didático y tampoco es que profundice mucho para explicar los temas. Según el laboratorio, debo hacer un arreglo para almacenar los datos del candidado, lo que no sé es si hacer el arreglo dentro de la clase Candidato.java o crear una nueva clase para el arreglo

Comment: Lo que entiendo que se pide es crear un arreglo de candidatos y otra matriz que tenga los votos (arreglo bidimensional de enteros). No veo muy adecuada esa estructura, pues la relación va a ser confiando en que la primera posición de tu arreglo de candidatos coincide con la primera fila de tu matriz de votos

Comment: He pensado crear otra estructura que establezca directamente la matriz, sin embargo, no comprendo cómo hacer los métodos constructores adecuados.           String matrizVotos = new String [3] [4];

Answer (score 1):

Permíteme que te eche una mano.

Lo que yo he hecho es crear la Clase Candidato de la siguiente forma:

Como puedes observar he creado un Map para las votaciones, en donde la clave es cada una de tus pronvincias que a su vez es un enum, y el valor es el número de votos. No le encuentro sentido a almacenarlo en una Matriz a no ser, que lleges al acuerdo que tu fila 0 sea la la primera pronvincia, la fila 1 la segunda y así. El inconveniente de usar la matriz como estructura es que no es dinámica. Además el Map te permite poder acceder por el valor de la clave que corresponde exáctemante con el nombre de la provincia sobre la cual quieres consultar su votaciones.

```
package dominio;

import java.util.*;

public class Candidato {

    // Primero definimos los atributos de tu clase    
    private String nombre;
    private String cedula;
    private int edad;
    private Provincia provincia;
    Map<Provincia, Integer> votaciones = new HashMap<Provincia, Integer>();

    public Candidato() {
        // El constructor vacío se va a encargar de inicializar el Map de votaciones
        // de momento con 0 votantes para cada provincia asociado al Objeto Candidato.
        this.votaciones.put(provincia.ALAJUELA, 0);
        this.votaciones.put(provincia.CARTAGO, 0);
        this.votaciones.put(provincia.GUANACASTE, 0);
        this.votaciones.put(provincia.PUNTARENAS, 0);
    }

    public Candidato(String nombre, String cedula, int edad) {
        this();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public Map<Provincia, Integer> getVotaciones() {
        return votaciones;
    }

    public void setVotaciones(Map<Provincia, Integer> votaciones) {
        this.votaciones = votaciones;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Candidato{nombre=").append(nombre);
        sb.append(", cedula=").append(cedula);
        sb.append(", edad=").append(edad);
        sb.append(", votaciones=").append(votaciones);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

// Aquí tienes el enum:

```
package dominio;

public enum Provincia {
    PUNTARENAS,
    ALAJUELA,
    CARTAGO,
    GUANACASTE;
}
```

Y por último te he realizado un programa principal en donde puedes testear el resultado final:

```
package principal;

import dominio.Candidato;
import java.util.*;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Candidato> candidatos = new ArrayList<>();

        
        Candidato candidato1 = new Candidato("Nasry Asfura", "xxxxxx", 63);
        Candidato candidato2 = new Candidato("Xiomara Castro ", "yyyyyy", 62);
        Candidato candidato3 = new Candidato("Yani Benjamín", "zzzzzzz", 56);

        candidatos.add(candidato1);
        candidatos.add(candidato2);
        candidatos.add(candidato3);

        candidatos.forEach(candidato -> {
            System.out.println("Votaciones del candidato " + candidato.getNombre() + " ");
            var votaciones = candidato.getVotaciones();
            var provincias = votaciones.keySet();
            provincias.forEach(provincia -> {
                System.out.println("Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de " + provincia + ": ");
                votaciones.put(provincia,Integer.parseInt(lectura.nextLine()));
            });
            System.out.println("------------");
        });
        
        candidatos.forEach(candidato -> {
            System.out.println("candidato = " + candidato);
            
        });
        
    }

}
```

Y la salida es esta, usando valores arbitrarios de número de votos:

```
Votaciones del candidato Nasry Asfura 
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de GUANACASTE: 
12314
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de PUNTARENAS: 
312515
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de CARTAGO: 
3123125
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de ALAJUELA: 
3123125
------------
Votaciones del candidato Xiomara Castro  
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de GUANACASTE: 
312315
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de PUNTARENAS: 
13213125
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de CARTAGO: 
86565
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de ALAJUELA: 
56482
------------
Votaciones del candidato Yani Benjamín 
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de GUANACASTE: 
31251
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de PUNTARENAS: 
312516
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de CARTAGO: 
3126624
Numero de votantes en la pronvicia de ALAJUELA: 
3125
------------
candidato = Candidato{nombre=Nasry Asfura, cedula=xxxxxx, edad=63, votaciones={GUANACASTE=12314, PUNTARENAS=312515, CARTAGO=3123125, ALAJUELA=3123125}}
candidato = Candidato{nombre=Xiomara Castro , cedula=yyyyyy, edad=62, votaciones={GUANACASTE=312315, PUNTARENAS=13213125, CARTAGO=86565, ALAJUELA=56482}}
candidato = Candidato{nombre=Yani Benjamín, cedula=zzzzzzz, edad=56, votaciones={GUANACASTE=31251, PUNTARENAS=312516, CARTAGO=3126624, ALAJUELA=3125}}
```

Espero que te sirva a de ayuda, y te haya podido enseñar algo nuevo!!
Recibe un cordial saluda amigo!!

Comment: Podrías estaría interesante calcular el total de votos de cada candidato y decir así cúal es el ganador de las elecciones 

Comment: Estimado: Muchas gracias por echarme la mano, no se me habría ocurrido usar esa forma porque no hemos visto eso en el curso de programación. Voy a tomar sus sugerencias. De verdad, estoy muy agradecido

Comment: De nada Leonel, estamos para ayudar y si puedes aprender una cosa nueva, genial. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes trabajar con tu idea inicial de crear una matriz (arreglo bidimensional) de enteros, para ello las columnas puede ser la cantidad de provincias y las filas puede ser la cantidad de candidatos.
Ejemplo

```
matriz[2][3]=5;
//Nos indicara que el Candidato 3 obtuvo 5 votos en la provincia 4
```

Comenzamos a codificar

**CLASE CANDIDATO**

```
public class Candidato {
    private String nombre;
    private String cedula;
    private int edad;
    private int cantidadVotos;

    public Candidato(String nombre, String cedula, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.cantidadVotos++;
    }

   //métodos set y get   
}
```

**CLASE PROVINCIA**
podríamos crear una clase [enum](https://jarroba.com/enum-enumerados-en-java-con-ejemplos/) pero para esta oportunidad vamos a trabajar con una clase normal.

```
public class Provincia {
    private String nombre;

    public Provincia(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
        
//método set y get
}
```

**CLASE ELECCIONES**
Creamos un método para agregar las 4 provincias

```
    public Provincia[] ingresarProvincias(){ 
        //Creamos un arreglo de longitud 4
        //agregamos los nombres de las provincias en cada posicion
        Provincia[]listaProvincias=new Provincia[4];
        listaProvincias[0]=new Provincia("Puntarenas");
        listaProvincias[1]=new Provincia("Alajuela");
        listaProvincias[2]=new Provincia("Cartago");
        listaProvincias[3]=new Provincia("Guanacaste");        
        return listaProvincias;
    }
```

Método para agregar a los candidatos, para esto vamos hacer uso del [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) porque no sabemos cuantos candidatos se van agregar, a diferencia de método de para agregar las provincias que hacemos uso de un arreglo estático porque sabemos que va existir 4 elementos.

```
    public ArrayList<Candidato> ingresarCandidatos(){
        //como no sabemos cuantos candidatos van a postular creamos un 
        //ArrayList de Candidato
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Candidato> listaCandidatos=new ArrayList<>();
        String nombre;
        String cedula;
        int edad;
        String respuesta;
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingresar datos del candidato");
            System.out.print("Nombre: ");
            nombre=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Cedula: ");
            cedula=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Edad: ");
            edad=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            Candidato candidato= new Candidato(nombre, cedula, edad);
            listaCandidatos.add(candidato);
            System.out.println("Desea ingresar otro candidato? (s/n): ");
            respuesta=sc.nextLine();
        }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
        
        return listaCandidatos;
    }
```

Métodos para buscar la posición del nombre de la provincia y el candidato al momento de emitir nuestro voto, una vez tengamos los 2 posiciones podemos sumar un voto en la matriz

```
   public int buscarPosicionProvincia(Provincia[] provincias,String nombre){
        int indice=0;
        //buscamos la posicion donde se guardo el nombre de provincia que estamos buscando
        for(int i=0;i<provincias.length;i++){
            if(provincias[i].getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre))
            {
                indice=i;
            }
        }        
        return indice;    
    }
    
    public int buscarPosicionCandidato(ArrayList<Candidato> candidatos, String nombre){
        int indice=0;
        
        int incremento=0;
        
         //buscamos la posicion donde se guardo el nombre del candidato que estamos buscando
        for(Candidato c:candidatos){
            if(c.getNombre().equals(nombre)){
                indice=incremento;
            }
            incremento++;
        }
        return indice;    
    }
```

Método para mostrar los votos de cada candidato por cada provincia

```
   public void mostrarVotos(int matriz[][], ArrayList<Candidato>candidatos, Provincia[]provincias){
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("**********************************************************");
        System.out.println("Mostrando votos de candidatos por provincia");
        for (Candidato candidato : candidatos) {
            System.out.println("Candidato: "+candidato.getNombre());
            //recorremos cada columna y mostramos los votos para 
            //cada provincia de cada uno de los candidatos
            for (int j = 0; j < provincias.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Provincia : "+provincias[j].getNombre());
                System.out.println("Cantidad de votos: "+matriz[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            i++;
        }    
    }
```

Método main, donde realizamos la simulación de las votaciones, para ello cada votante tiene que escribir el nombre del candidato a quien va dirigido su voto y el nombre de la provincia donde está votando, con una interfaz gráfica se miraría mejor

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String nombreCandidato;
        String nombreProvincia;
        int columna;
        int fila;       
        String respuesta="";//para continuar emitiendo voto        
        Elecciones e= new Elecciones();
        //obtenemos el listado de provincias
        Provincia[]listaProvincias=e.ingresarProvincias();
        //obtenemos el listado de candidatos
        ArrayList<Candidato> listaCandidatos=e.ingresarCandidatos(); 
        
        //creamos una matriz que va contener las cantidades de votos
        //filas son las posiciones de los candidatos
        //columnas son las posiciones de las provincias
        int matrizVotos[][] =new int[listaCandidatos.size()][4];
        
        do{
            
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la provincia donde se emite el voto: ");
                nombreProvincia=sc.nextLine();
                //obtenemos la posicion de la provincia en el arreglo
                columna=e.buscarPosicionProvincia(listaProvincias, nombreProvincia);                
                
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del candidato a quien va su voto: ");
                nombreCandidato=sc.nextLine();
                //obtenemos la posicion del candidato en el ArrayList
                fila=e.buscarPosicionCandidato(listaCandidatos, nombreCandidato);                
                //aumentamos en 1 el voto de la posicion (fila,columna)
                matrizVotos[fila][columna]=matrizVotos[fila][columna]+1;
                System.out.print("Desea emitir otro voto? (s/n)");
                respuesta=sc.nextLine(); 
                //mientras respuesta es s/S seguimos emitiendo voto
        }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
       //Mostramos por votos de cada candidato en cada provincia 
       e.mostrarVotos(matrizVotos,listaCandidatos, listaProvincias);       
    }
```

Fácilmente podríamos hacer uso de patrones de diseño, lambdas, collections entre otros pero observando tu pregunta da entender que estas comenzando con la programación y no viene al caso apresurar en ver esos temas aunque sería bueno que vayas revisando como se usan.